# How do i create a 2d canvas and a 3d canvas only using camera?

Tags: javascript, jquery, 3d, three.js, wireframe

I made 2 cameras, both are fine... I want one camera to render everything in wireframe and the other 3d. they both render on different canvases. I tried having the objects change material to a wireframe material, but i fear it will cause lag. They are changed after the 3d is rendered but before the 2d canvas is rendered. So is there a way to have wireframe without doing every mesh just for one camera? PS, I want both canvases rendering the same scene

Comment: "but i fear it will cause lag" Have you tried it? That might just be the solution to your problem.

Comment: Yes i have, but ive only tested with a few cubes, and the end project will have 100s or 1000s

Comment: So add more cubes. You should be testing under realistic conditions. If anything, you should *over* test. Add *more* cubes than you expect to see and see how it performs.

Comment: are we not allowed to use arrays for the cubes?
var cube[i] = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color:Math.random() * 0xb60430} ) );

Comment: http://hastebin.com/uqulirupoq.avrasm I fixed it, but i dont understand why color isnt changed